# Unable to display PrimeNg toasts when switching pages

Tags: angular, primeng, toast

I'm trying to use the [PrimeNg Toasts](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/toast) to confirm the deletion of one user.

Basically, here is my code:

```
  deleteUser() {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: this.translateService.instant('common.messages.deletion-confirm'),
      header: this.translateService.instant('common.messages.deletion-title'),
      icon: 'fa-light fa-triangle-exclamation',
      acceptLabel: this.translateService.instant('common.messages.ok'),
      rejectLabel: this.translateService.instant('common.messages.cancel'),
      rejectButtonStyleClass: 'p-button-secondary p-button-text',

      accept: async () => {
        await this.userSettingsService.deleteUser(this.store.selectSnapshot(state => state.userSettings.activeUser.id));
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'User deleted', detail: 'User deleted successfully' });
      },
    });
  }
```

The `userSettingsService` will call the backend and ask for a route change(to go to the user list) in case of success.

According to my tests, the messageService only tries to display a toast in the current component, if I set a component in a parent component(like my layout component), it is just not displayed.

Since I'm transitioning from my user page to the user list page, I'm not sure how it would be possible to set a `<p-toast>`.
I've tried to put:

- one in a parent component
- one in the user detail page
- one in the user list page
- one at each page

But nothing gets displayed. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `<p-toast>` in `app.component.ts`.

In another cause, Make sure you provided only single `MessageService` in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having the MessageService in my SharedModule, which is imported in all module instead of my CoreModule which is only imported in AppModule. Thank you very much!!!